# Polluting agents generated by road traffic in a city

Tags: combustion, toxicity, fuel

I want to measure the air quality according to road traffic in a city.
What are the polluting agents (generated by fuel combustion) strictly related and generated by road vehicles that is worth measuring?

Among $\ce{CO}$, $\ce{CO2}$, $\ce{NO_$x$}$, PM2.5, PM10, $\ce{NH3}$, $\ce{O3}$, $\ce{SO2}$ which are the most significative? Should I add or remove any agent?

Comment: You might also want consider the metals which appear in road dust, I recall having seen some work on neutron activation anaylsis of dusts collected near roads. The rubber tyres are likely to contain some metals such as zinc.

Comment: That's a homework assignment, isn't it?

Comment: No, I am asking for a real project. There are different electronic devices capable of measuring different agents and I want understand what I should look for.

Comment: Why has it been tagged as opinion based?

Comment: @FrancescoBoi Because it's very arbitrary what pollutant is significant. For whom? People who are astmathic? Pregnant? Pedestrians or people in nearby flats? Etc.

Comment: Even for pollution coming from road vehicles like cars and motorikes?

Comment: There are cities which periodically monitor the air pollution such as Seoul to inform their inhabitants: what agents do they measure?

Comment: Ask Seoul. Or the internet, more conveniently.

Comment: Thank you very much. so useful, never thought about that.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want consider the metals which appear in road dust, I recall having seen some work on neutron activation anaylsis of dusts collected near roads. The rubber tyres are likely to contain some metals. Cars will be likely to release metals in other ways. I would consider the dust from the operation of disk brakes, the wear on tyres, fuel additives and also corrosion of bodywork and engine parts. I know that zinc and cadmium plated parts can release both ionic and particulate forms of these metals.

One paper on the subject was by Siddique et. al. im Radiochimica Acta, 2013, volume 101, pages 273-277.

It is interesting that lead levels in the air have fallen since leaded petrol was banned in the UK, but some workers have reported finding platinum group metals in the air near to roads.

Using ICPMS Simitchiev et. al, in TALANTA, 2008, volume 77, pages 889-896 found Pt, Rh and Pd in road dust.